# "E: Unable to locate package mtp-tools", although universe repository is enabled. "AppStream cache update failed"

Tags: apt, virtualbox, windows-7

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and installed the iso file as a virtual machine in VirtualBox running on Windows 7.

I enabled the universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

I got this result:

```
'universe' distribution component enabled for all sources
```

I updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got this result:

```
AppStream cache update failed
```

I then tried to download a package:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools
```

I got this result:

```
E:  Unable to locate package mtp-tools
```

Comment: How do I enable the "universe" respository?

Comment: Thanks for the update! There is no `libmtp` package in Xenial, however there is a `libmtp9` package. Though I don't know what you hope to achieve with its installation since it doesn't contain any executables. Considering the content of the linked article, do you you perhaps mean to install [`mtp-tools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mtp-tools) or [`mtpfs`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mtpfs)? Those contain directly useful utilities that depend on `libmtp9` and will install it as a dependency.

Comment: Dupe? https://askubuntu.com/q/761592/158442