# Running command sudo apt-get update, getting error "Error while moving old databse out of the way" App stream cache update failed

Tags: database, cache, appstream

Error while moving old database out of the way. App stream cache update failed

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761592/unable-to-apt-get-dist-upgrade-on-a-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-usb