# Updating package lists in 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, appstream

I'm running 16.04 from a thumb drive and receiving an error message when I attempt to update package lists.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20180228) xenial InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20180228) xenial Release
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]       
Fetched 216 kB in 0s (267 kB/s)                                                

** (appstreamcli:5066): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
Reading package lists... Done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can check existence of */var/cache/app-info/xapian/default* directory and/or force index refresh with `sudo appstreamcli refresh-index --force`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851310/66509) for details.

Comment: I did look for an answer to this question before posting and did not find one...perhaps I worded my search incorrectly. Correct me if I'm wrong,  but doesn't this solution simply move/rename the /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default directory to /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default-old and then back again? Which did seem to solve the issue, btw.